# How to change the default header labels of Pivot Tables with Office JS

Tags: excel, pivot-table, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

I am printing the **Pivot table** using **office JS** API.

I want to replace/change the header labels by code using Office JS.
[image]

Comment: See [Work with PivotTables using the Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-pivottables) for available properties and methods.